# Laravel Factory error Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes)

Tags: laravel-7, laravel-seeding

I want to generate dummy data using factory with seeder so it will give me the error.
when I run this command given below:
`php artisan db:seed`

so here it's the error.

*PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in D:\xampp\htdocs\Bootstrap\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\Grammar.php on line 1120
PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in Unknown on line 0*

```
class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        factory(User::class,5)->create()->each(function ($user){
            $profile = factory(Profile::class)->make();
            $user->profile()->save($profile);
            $profile->each(function ($profiles){
                $qualification =factory(Qualification::class,3)->make();
                $experience =factory(Experience::class,3)->make();
                $profiles->qualification()->saveMany($qualification);
                $profiles->experience()->saveMany($experience);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

For each User has-one Profile.
For each Profile Has-many (Qualification and Experience).

If we run this code given below:

```
class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
   
    public function run()
    {
        DB::table('posts')->insertOrIgnore([
            ['id'=>1,'title'=>'admission','created_at'=>now(),'updated_at'=>now()],
            ['id'=>2,'title'=>'biology','created_at'=>now(),'updated_at'=>now()],
            ['id'=>3,'title'=>'mathematics','created_at'=>now(),'updated_at'=>now()],
            ['id'=>4,'title'=>'chemistry','created_at'=>now(),'updated_at'=>now()],
            ['id'=>5,'title'=>'physics','created_at'=>now(),'updated_at'=>now()],
            ['id'=>6,'title'=>'english','created_at'=>now(),'updated_at'=>now()],
            ['id'=>7,'title'=>'urdu','created_at'=>now(),'updated_at'=>now()],
        ]);
        DB::table('provinces')->insertOrIgnore([
            ['id'=>1,'title'=>'punjab','created_at'=>now(),'updated_at'=>now()],
            ['id'=>2,'title'=>'sindh','created_at'=>now(),'updated_at'=>now()],
            ['id'=>3,'title'=>'nwfp','created_at'=>now(),'updated_at'=>now()],
            ['id'=>4,'title'=>'balochistan','created_at'=>now(),'updated_at'=>now()],
        ]);

    }
}
```

using this command `php artisan db:seed`
then there is no error received.

please help me in using a laravel factory.